# Get lat/long from tile z/x/y filename

Tags: tilemill

I am trying to derive a latitude/longitude from the filename of maptiles generated from TileMill (zoom/x/y).

Using information from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames I am using (PHP implementation)

```
$n = pow(2, $zoom);
$lon_deg = $x / $n * 360.0 - 180.0;
$lat_deg = rad2deg(atan(sinh(pi() * (1 - 2 * $y / $n))));
echo $lat_deg.','.$lon_deg;
```

to calculate from a maptile named z-x-y.png.

The value returned from the calculation does not related to the area covered by the tile.

An example being 7-36-70 (Jamaica) which returns a value of 16.875,61.6063963714 (location in the Arabian Sea).

Can anyone spot what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n should be 128, if that is 2**7. So, is that what your $n comes to?

Then $lon_deg should be 36/128*360 - 180 which would be -78.75 by my reckoning, if you assume the correct bracketing/precedence is (36/128)*360-180. And that looks pretty close to Jamaica...

Comment: $n is 128 and the value coming out of $lon_deg is now -78.75 (slight edit made to get there, workings below...     
$n = 128;  
$lon_deg = 36 / 128 * 360.0 - 180.0;  
$lon_deg = -78.75;

But this is still not the expected value (somewhere around 18.0, -77.3)

Comment: Can you check $y is 70?

Comment: I feel like the long value is now correct (on the correct line of longitude) but the latitude is flipped across the equator (a negative value, when a positive would be correct)??

Comment: The answer should be negative because (1-140/128) will be negative as will the sinh() and atan().

Comment: Try replacing everything inside the sinh() with -0.2945240625

Comment: rad2deg(atan(sinh(-0.2945240625)))

Comment: That gives -16.6361918784

Comment: Which is good as it corresponds to Jamaica! All I did to get the -0.2945 was 3.1415*(1-2*70/128) which means your maths has gone wrong in that bit!

Comment: But it doesn't correspond to Jamaica, that's a positive 16.x value?

Comment: Adding a - seems to work
rad2deg(atan(sinh(M_PI * -(1 - (2 * $y) / $n))));

Comment: Final solution is...
$n = pow(2, $zoom);
$lon_deg = ($x/$n*360.0)-180.0;
$lat_deg = rad2deg(atan(sinh(M_PI * -(1 - (2 * $y) / $n))));
echo $lat_deg.','.$lon_deg;

Thanks @mark-setchell for your help.